# Why did my friend write 发发发 on her note?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Today I went to an ice-cream shop with my Chinese friend, and we wrote notes to stick on the wall.  My friend wrote:

> [image]
>
> [开心](http://dict.cn/%E5%BC%80%E5%BF%83)、[健康](http://dict.cn/%E5%81%A5%E5%BA%B7)、[平安](http://dict.cn/%E5%B9%B3%E5%AE%89)、发发发
> kāixīn, jiànkāng, píng'ān, fā fā fā

The first three items are ordinary well wishes, but I have no idea why she would write 发发发.  I asked her about it, but she couldn't explain it to me.

**Question**: Why did my friend write 发发发 on her note?

Searing for 发发发 at [YouDao](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E5%8F%91%E5%8F%91%E5%8F%91) gives inappropriate suggestions, and it's not listed at [Dict.cn](http://dict.cn/%E5%8F%91%E5%8F%91%E5%8F%91), nor [Line Dict](http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/example?query=%E5%8F%91%E5%8F%91%E5%8F%91), nor [小马词典](http://www.xiaoma.info/compound.php?cp=%E5%8F%91%E5%8F%91%E5%8F%91).

Comment: I think it's short for **發財**.

Comment: droooze, short? But it IS a funny way to say 发财.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 发：Short for 发财，make a fortune，become rich。

Chinese people like to use reiterative locution to emphasize the strong meaning or wish. Other cases like: 好好好、 旺旺旺、棒棒棒、赞赞赞。
Sometimes you will also see 888 instead of 发发发，because 888(bababa) has similar pronunciation with 发发发(fafafa) and much easier to write/type.

Comment: 666 is another common one - not for the devil though.

Comment: @user3306356 Aha, yes, you're right!

Comment: @user3306356 Presumably not as a stand-in for 发财 either, since _liù_ doesn’t exactly sound like either _fā_ or _cái_… so what is 666 used for? I’ve only ever seen it used to mean ‘exaggerated floods of tears’ (because 666 is ‘one more’ than 555, which sounds like 呜呜呜).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet 666 stand for 六六六(means smoothly,顺利) or 溜溜溜(means proficiency,熟练)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was just adding it to Bruce’s list of “other cases,” perhaps I didn’t make that clear. 666 can also be for 牛牛牛 (poor southern accents!) to mean awesome, amazing, wicked.

Answer (score 12):

发发发;

发 is short for 发财（get rich, make a fortune）. There is a catch saying: 重要的事情说三遍(important things should be reiterated three times). This is kind of emphasis for its importance. That's why people usually put three 发s: 发发发. They wish you make a great deal of money!

Comment: Note that 重要的事情说三遍 is an online meme/catchphrase popular since 2015, but 发发发 or the phenomenon of triplets has been widely used long before.

Comment: @dans On the contrary, the origin of “重要的事情说三遍” is disputed and all proposed origins has no direct relation with the historical Chinese usage-- variant of popular Japanese ACG catchphrase; Japanese comedy shows; Japanese commercials.  “重要的事情说三遍” cannot be used as an explain the origin of “发发发” but the existence of phrases such as “发发发” and techniques of using three-time-repetition to prove a point both prompted the invention and popularization of “重要的事情说三遍”.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I'm not writing a competing answer because there already is one.